# How to set React V4 BrowserHistory to work?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redirect, browser-history

My **React** version is '**^16.6.1**' and **Router** version is '**^4.3.1**'.

Before **V4** I could route through pages programmatically using `browserhistory`.

But now I can't do it. I did it using `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'`. It changes the url as I want. But it didn't change the page. It stays in the previous page.

Please give me a solution.

This is my code.

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

//App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from './firebase';
import Routes from "./Routes";
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isLogged: false };
    let ctx = this;
    const history = createHistory();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log("logged in");
            history.replace('/home');
            ctx.setState({ isLogged : true});
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            console.log("not logged in");
            ctx.setState({ isLogged : false});
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavigationBar />
        <Routes />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

//Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/Admin/Login';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Orchids from './components/Orchids/Orchids';
import Anthurium from './components/Anthurium/Anthurium';
import ContactUs from './components/ContactUs/ContactUs';
import AddOrchid from './components/Admin/AddOrchid';

export default (props) =>
  <Switch>
    {/* <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} /> */}
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/orchids" component={Orchids} />
    <Route path="/anthurium" component={Anthurium} />
    <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/add-orchid" component={AddOrchid} />
  </Switch>;
```

Comment: Try `history.push('/home');`

Comment: I add both history.push() & history.replace(). But the result is same. The only URL is changed without page changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) from the `react-router-dom` module you can simply use `this.props.history.push("/yourPath")` in children of the BrowserRouter component.